# Не выполняется код, после вызова winforms

Tags: c#, windows, selenium, forms

Всем доброго дня
Почему-то не выполняется код, который в примере в скобках, после `startJob`:

```
// Парсим категорию
List<IWebElement> allThemes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'chat-comm-theme text-addition')]/span")).ToList();
MyVariables.nowCategory = allThemes.Last().Text;

MessageBox.Show($"Категория вопроса: {MyVariables.nowCategory}");

JobWindow realJob = new JobWindow();
realJob.Show();

if(MyVariables.startJob = true)
{
    if (MyVariables.insertFullAnswer == true)
    {
        // Получаем ФИО клиента и вбиваем в поле для ответа.
        IWebElement clientName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h3[contains(@class, 'icon-and-text-m')]"));
        string nameTxt = clientName.Text;
        string textToPaste = $"Здравствуйте, {nameTxt}.\n Благодарим за обращение.\n {MyVariables.fullAnswerText} \n\n Благодарим за ожидание ответа.";
        Clipboard.SetText(textToPaste);

        // Клик на поле для ответа
        IWebElement textAreaForAnswer = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[contains(@class, 'textarea-element')]"));
        textAreaForAnswer.Click();
        textAreaForAnswer.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "a");
        textAreaForAnswer.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "delete");
        textAreaForAnswer.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v");
    }

    if (MyVariables.insertFullAnswer == true)
    {
        // Закрываем текущее окно с обращением
        IWebElement closeNowQuestion = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class,'tab-item')]/span[contains(text(),'Покупатель')]//following-sibling::custom-svg-icon[contains(@classname,'icon-white')]"));
        closeNowQuestion.Click();
        Thread.Sleep(1500);

        goto nextQuestionViaJob;
    }
}
```

те до вызова:

```
JobWindow realJob = new JobWindow();
realJob.Show();
```

все идет как надо, а дальше, даже если переменные `true`, не выполняется

С чем это может быть связано?
в форме нажимаю "вставить", она закрывается, но дальше работа не идет

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что ваши условия проверяются после закрытия формы? Попробуйте заменить Show на ShowDialog...

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Ещё в `if (MyVariables.startJob = true)` исправьте `=` на `==`, и вместо `if (MyVariables.startJob == true)` можете писать `if (MyVariables.startJob)`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, исправлю